# Python, using nested lists (list of lists) from user input

Tags: python

**Update: I am new to stack overflow but have quickly realised 'good' questions need to be asked which I never realised before. Also my coding skills are not the best hence the mess of my code block. Sorry, i have edited my question**

I have a simple coding question, however i am struggling with the last part of this question regarding list of lists. Can someone help please? :)

The question is:

> Write a Python code to ask a user to enter students’ information including name, last name and student ID number. The program should continue prompting the user to enter information until the user enters zero. Then the program enters search mode. In this mode, the user can enter a student ID number to retrieve the corresponding student’s information. If the user enters zero, the program stops. (Hint: consider using list of lists).

Here is my code so far:

```
print("Enter First name, last name and Student ID number. Then press 0 to continue")

userFirst = str(input("Enter First Here:"))
userLast = str(input("Enter Last Name:"))
userStudent = int(input("Enter Student ID number:"))
userInfo = input("Enter more details or pres 0 to enter search mode")

while userInfo != "0":
    userInfo=input("Enter more details")
else:
        print("Search Mode")

searchMode = []
searchMode.append(userFirst)
searchMode.append(userLast)
searchMode.append(userStudent)

userSearch = int(input("Enter Student ID"))
userSearch = [[userStudent]]
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and ["Why is 'can someone help me?' not an actual question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/).

Comment: input is a string by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I'm understanding correctly, the "Lists of List" comment pertains to nested Lists, The code you have is close to what's needed.
I believe this is what you need.

```
print("Enter First name, last name and Student ID number. Then press 0 to continue")

userFirst = str(input("Enter First Here:"))
userLast = str(input("Enter Last Name:"))
userStudent = int(input("Enter Student ID number:"))
userInfo = input("Enter more details or pres 0 to enter search mode")

while userInfo != "0":
    userInfo=input("Enter more details")
else:
        print("Search Mode")

###Changed SearchMode to be nested list with each list Holding the input values from [ [UserFirst],[userLast],[userStuden] ]
searchMode = [[],[],[]]
    ### Append userFirst to the first Indexed List
searchMode[0].append(userFirst)
    ### Append userLast to the second Indexed List
searchMode[1].append(userLast)
    ### Append userStudent to the third Indexed List
searchMode[2].append(userStudent)

userSearch = int(input("Enter Student ID"))

### Since we know that we need to search by The Student Id we Take the InitialList and add the index of our desired Nested List; In this Case it's the 3rd nested
### Then we take the values from the nested List and look for the inputted value and obtain the record corresponding index
userSearch = searchMode[2][userStudent-1]
print(userSearch)
```

Let me know if this doesn't give you the results you need and I'll try working on it some more

update:
For the fun of it, I recreated the process to be called as a function.

```
def SearchRequest():
    ### This Will Hold our Input Data
    SearchData = [[],[],[],[]]

    ### This Will Run The Question Prompts We Want Filled
    def promptQuestions():

        # Get User First Name
        def userFirst():
            return SearchData[0].append(str(input('Enter First Name Here: ')))

        # Get User Last Name
        def userLast():
            return SearchData[1].append(str(input('Enter Last Name Here: ')))
        # Get User Student ID
        def userStudent():
            return SearchData[2].append(int(input('Enter Student ID Number: ')))

        # Ask If They Want to Add Additional Info; Entering 0 Will Exit The Asking Phase
        # Once Completed We Will Start the UserId Lookup Phase
        def userInfo():
            #Beginning Prompt
            userInfo = input('Enter More Details Or Press 0 to Enter Search Mode')
            #List We'll Be Using To Hold Inputs
            output = []
            #Append First input To our Output List
            output.append(userInfo)

            while userInfo != "0":
                #If 0 Was Not Entered: Ask To Enter More Details
                userInfo=input('Enter More Details: ')
                #Append Details To Our Output List
                output.append(userInfo)
            else:
                print('Entering Search Mode')
                #Append Result List To Our Main Search Data
                SearchData[3].append(output)

        # Ending Of Prompt Questions
        def runQuestions():
            """This will be used to hold the order of execution"""
            userFirst()
            userLast()
            userStudent()
            userInfo()
            return SearchData
        return runQuestions()

        #Create a Search Mode Allowing User To Lookup ID
    def SearchMode():
            #Gets Input ID to LookUP
        def SearchStudentID():
            return int(input('Enter Student ID: '))
        #Returns the matching ID as long as the ID is the same as the index Number
        return SearchData[2][SearchStudentID()-1]


    # Final Layer to Our Searching Process
    def runSearchProcess():

        #Begins Main Prompt Phase
        promptQuestions()

        #Once Everything is completed, Return the search Modes Result
        return SearchMode()
    #Ending Of Search Request
    return runSearchProcess()


print(SearchRequest())
```

Comment: Thank you for you feedback, Sorry for the late reply. I ran the code and got the following error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test.py", line 26, in <module>
    userSearch = searchMode[2][userStudent-1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: were any changes in the code made? 
if not, what was being inputted so I can recreate the error

Comment: so i put j in first name, s in the second name and 55 in student ID. I then put 55 into the student id input field which returned the error. Thank you